# MinSdkVersion 'L' that I didn't specify in the Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I'm already saw related posts. I'm changed my dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
```

and in my **main** project gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
```

in subprojects but it doesn't help me. I'm convinced that all subprojects (libraries) in my project doesn't use the newest version of this libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug. Use MAx SDK 19 until it's fixed.

Comment: I'm tried your solution but it didn't help me.

Comment: It must be a bug then. Use 19 until Android fixes it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm changed `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 19. Now project already run. But will run the application on the Android L?